# Passing string from edit text to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I have looked through the example here on stack overflow. However, I can't get a solution that works correctly. My application still crashes. How do I pass the string from an edit text in one activity to another activity?

This is my code from the first activity:

```
Button btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EditText etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_location);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("location", etLocation.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Code from Second Activity:

```
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String str = intent.getStringExtra("location");
textView1.setText(str);
```

Comment: Can you post crash Logcat details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyCurrentActivityClass.this, NextActivity.class);
```

Make sure NextActivity is in the Manifest. In the first case you're not providing enough info to start the activity.

Comment: your a lifesaver man thank you so much, can't believe I made such a silly mistake

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

From first activity send like this:

```
btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EditText etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_location);
       Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
        i.putExtra("location", etLocation.getText().toString());      
        startActivity(i);
}
});
```

And in second activity do like this:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String tv1= in.getExtras().getString("location");
textView1.setText(tv1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should get your information from the second activity this way:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String myLocation= extras.getString("location");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare a variable textview1? Change

textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); to

TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);