# Android: Fetch user inputs from one activity and display them on another activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I am building an android app in which, on the ***MainActivity*** the user enters his/her details like name, phone number, etc., in several EditText fields. I should get all those data, pass them to the ***SecondActivity*** and display them on textViews. The transition from MainActivity to second activity is done via an onclick event.

**Edit text xml**

```
<EditText
     android:hint="@string/teacher_name_hint"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="10"
     android:id="@+id/teacher_name"
     android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,., "
     android:inputType="textPersonName"
     android:maxLength="42"
     android:maxLines="2"
     android:minLines="1"
     android:textColorHint="@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light" />
```

**Onclick Event**

```
public void roll_sheet_Activity(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Roll_sheet.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: pass data one activity to other activity@Ved Sarkar

Comment: pass your data from one activity to another activity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146614/how-to-send-string-from-one-activity-to-another?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: using bundle you can send data from one activity to another activity

Comment: Please try searching for these things first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481516/passing-string-from-edit-text-to-another-activity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052019/how-to-send-text-from-one-activity-to-another-activity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172176/how-to-send-multiple-edittexts-in-to-another-activity-as-a-textviews-like-login
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182906/how-to-pass-edit-text-data-in-form-of-string-to-next-activity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172176/how-to-send-multiple-edittexts-in-to-another-activity-as-a-textviews-like-login

Answer (score 0):

Pass data using intent

```
public void roll_sheet_Activity(View v)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("stringName", stringName);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

on the next activity:

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("stringName");
```